# How to track the FCM push notification whether is is delivered or not using message id

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using PHP Restful service to send push notification to android device using Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM).

Using the following URL i am able to post the message to the FCM successfully and getting corresponsing message id.

https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

But how to know the whether the message is delivered to the device or not using above message id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try my below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple case of a JSON message successfully sent to one recipient without canonical IDs in the response:

```
{ "multicast_id": 108,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:08" }
  ]
}
```

Here are JSON results for 6 recipients (IDs 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, and 42 respectively) with 3 messages successfully processed, 1 canonical registration token returned, and 3 errors:

```
{ "multicast_id": 216,
  "success": 3,
  "failure": 3,
  "canonical_ids": 1,
  "results": [
    { "message_id": "1:0408" },
    { "error": "Unavailable" },
    { "error": "InvalidRegistration" },
    { "message_id": "1:1516" },
    { "message_id": "1:2342", "registration_id": "32" },
    { "error": "NotRegistered"}
  ]
}
```

The success will indicate the request is successfully processed. It may not tell the exact delivery of the message.

To make complete understanding please [read](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)

Comment: How do i know whether the notification was successfully sent to the user?

Comment: They don't guarantee delivery but they try for a max of 4 weeks to deliver the message depending on the duration you set in the message you send to Google's GCM servers if you wish to let Google keep the data for eventual delivery of msg to the device in case the device was offline when the message was to be delivered.

Comment: You can use upstream messaging to get delivery receipts (sent from CCS to your 3rd party app server) when a device confirms that it received a message sent by CCS.

Comment: can't we track the message using message id?

Comment: Not with HTTP connection server that you are using

Comment: could you please tell me how to use upstream messaging to get delivery receipts to the application server?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs. Google for its code if you want

Comment: Thanks Suhail, Can i use XMPP Connection within the PHP code itself?

Comment: yes its just xmpp https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref

Comment: Thanks Suhail for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this: in php side you get response from fcm like

```
{
    "multicast_id":8042731220476088762,
    "success":1,
    "failu‌‌​​re":0,
    "canonical_‌​i‌​ds":0,
    "results":[‌​{"message_id"‌​:"0:‌​1474456734183‌​863%97d‌​a1d69f9fd7e‌​cd"}]
}
```

so message is delivered to that id if success is 1

Comment: Yes i am getting this response, The success is 1 though message is not delivered to the device.And i would like to know whether the notifcation was successfully delivered to the user using message id

Comment: have you got any solution ? I have used node js for server side. its not receiving in ios device. but i got response like this.
successfully sent message  {
  results: [ { messageId: '0:1615964641473163%473af62ef9fd7ecd' } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 0,
  successCount: 1,
  multicastId: 2860856613764255000
}